# F test to determine lack of fit

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, goodness-of-fit

> Perform the F test to determine whether or not there is lack of fit of a linear regression function; use a significant level of 0.025. Compute the test statistic, reject region, and estimate the p-value. Is the model lack of fit for the data?

What is the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis here? I found $F$ using R with `anova(datR.mod,datF.mod)`, where `datR.mod` is the reduced model and `datF.mod` is the full model. I presume that this $F$ is the test statistic? And the rest follows from this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does the original really say "significant level"?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, copied verbatim

Comment: Okay, thanks. If it were me, after the word "significant" I'd add "[*sic*]" (Latin for "thus") to [clarify that the error was present in the original](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/sic/), but I'll leave that choice up to you.